# Codename not sending builds to server

Tags: codenameone

today I am experiencing issues with regard to sending Android build to server. Netbeans keeps hanging at the step of sending the build to my account and then after it gives me this error in the console:

```
java.io.IOException: Error writing to server
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:699)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:711)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1585)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$200(HttpURLConnection.java:91)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1484)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1482)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(AccessController.java:782)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1481)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
at com.codename1.build.client.BuildProcess.uploadToS3(BuildProcess.java:358)
at com.codename1.build.client.BuildProcess.sendS3Build(BuildProcess.java:386)
at com.codename1.build.client.BuildProcess.sendRequestToServer(BuildProcess.java:459)
at com.codename1.build.client.CodeNameOneBuildTask.execute(CodeNameOneBuildTask.java:505)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor75.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1361)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:261)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:574)
at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:128)
```

C:\Users\rmato\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FinalApp\arkountsapp\build.xml:346: Error in server build process
BUILD FAILED (total time: 10 minutes 21 seconds)

What could be the issue?

Comment: This seems to be a problem with your connection. Is cloud.codenameone.com accessible? Are you behind a firewall?